# Fantasy romance manhwa where the protagonist reincarnates in a novel where her husband was the villain

Tags: story-identification, manga, webcomics

The protagonist dies and is reincarnated in a novel as a character who tried to kill herself because she was married to a prince known to be cursed. She committed suicide in the novel because the prince (who the main villain in the novel) was known to be cursed and had marks in his face.

In the original novel (the one the protagonist read), her husband was the villain, but she liked the villain more than the original story's male lead. The heroine of the novel was the protagonist's sister.

In the novel, the villain was supposed to be the next king but the book's male lead (who was brother of villain) became the king. The curse was something like a bloodline curse. The original male lead wanted the protagonist later but the protagonist hated him and rejected him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Reincarnation into a novel is a pretty common trope. [The Villain's Savior](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-villains-savior) maybe? Or [Miss Not-So Sidekick](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/miss-not-so-sidekick)?

Comment: What colour was the female lead's hair?

Comment: Can you double check the edit I just made? Unfortunately, stories about reincarnating into another story really mess with the term "main character", since there's usually two sets of them. I tried to specify "original story" for the original set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *[The Little Princess and Her Monster Prince](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-little-princess-and-her-monster-prince)*, aka *I Became the Wife of the Monstrous Crown Prince*.

> Heroine has traveled back in time and entered the universe of "Lady and the Beast," a 19th century soft porn trashy novel. She finds herself in the body of Anthea, child bride of the **Monster Crown Prince Blake, who has been cursed to die at the age of 18** due to this sins of his ancestor. In the novel, Anthea should have **committed suicide after looking at the horrible cursed birth marks on Prince Blake's body**. But she tries to rewrite a part of the story by instilling confidence in Blake and showering him with unconditional love, just until he is ready to meet his "real" true love, Diana.

The synopsis is a solid match for the question. The main character reincarnates in a novel they read as a character that commits suicide upon seeing their husband's face. In the novel, she succeeds, but due to the reincarnation the story is altered. As mentioned in the question, the main character preferred the "monster" prince over his brother.

The MC and the "monster" prince:

[image: Anime disfigured]

Comment: this is the one. tnx

Comment: @TypicalDemon69 You're welcome. If this is the correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 3):

Could this be [The Villain's Savior](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-villains-savior)?

The main character awakens to find that she's a sidekick character in a romance book that she was reading. Her (real life) sister is also present, which represents a change to the book's plot as the heroine didn't have a sister. Her fated husband (to-be) is the book's villain and also a familiar person to her.

[image]

Comment: No, the one i read was where the protagonist was supposed to be dead